# If, Then, Else Scripting

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I have a log file that contains several lines, each with an IP, username, and URL. I need to create something that will take each IP in the line and, if starting with a 10 will append the word "ON" to the end of the line containing it. All other lines with any other IP not starting with a 10 will need to have the word "OFF" appended to it.

**Example of log file:**

```
10.10.10.10 jsmith1234 [URL] 
173.10.10.10 jsmith1234 [URL]
```

**Example of what I want:**

```
10.10.10.10 jsmith1234 [URL] ON
173.10.10.10 jsmith1234 [URL] OFF
```

I believe an if, then, else statement would work (used in a bash shell script), but I am very new to these and not sure where to start.

Comment: You should start with reading the manual for the shell or scripting language you want to use and then try things out. Then when you have concrete problems, come back here, post the program you got and any error messages.

Comment: I believe that `awk` or `sed` is what you want. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MatthewRock, thank you so much! I was making this a LOT harder than it needed to be. I got my command to work.
sed '/^10.*:/ s/$/ ON/' test_file.txt
Sometimes the best help is just to be pointed to the right place. I appreciate you being helpful rather than rude.

Comment: @sudo_maas Do you have any scripting language in mind? There are dozens of ways to do what you need. E.g. bash, sed, perl, awk, python, etc etc.

Comment: @andcoz I apologize for being so unclear. I was wanting to use bash; and thanks to the help on here I now know how to make it work with sed as well.

Comment: No problem. Please, post your solution as an answer to your own question, so this can help others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something?
short example:

```
while read line; do
    if [[ $line = \10.* ]] ; then
        echo "$line ON"
    else
        echo "$line OFF"
    fi
done
```

As a result:

```
user@:~$ cat testo.txt 
10.10.10.10 jsmith1234 [URL] 
173.10.10.10 jsmith1234 [URL]

user@:~$ bash testo.sh < testo.txt 
10.10.10.10 jsmith1234 [URL] ON
173.10.10.10 jsmith1234 [URL] OFF
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate you taking the time to help. I now know two ways I can make this work!

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem myself using the following solution:

```
sed '/^10.*:/ s/$/ ON/' test_file.txt

sed '/^10.*:/ s/$/ OFF/' test_file.txt
```

Comment: you missed "!", should be - "sed '/^10.*:/! s/$/ OFF/' test_file.txt"

Answer (score -1):

```
cat logfile | while read line
do
  echo ${line} | grep ^"10\." >/dev/null; r=${?}
  if [ ${r} -eq 0 ]
  then
    line=${line}" ON"
  else
    line=${line}" OFF"
  fi
echo ${line}
done > new_logfile
```